# Hibernate multitenancy fails after upgrade to 6.2

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant, spring-boot-3, hibernate-6.x

I am upgrading a Spring Boot project from 2.7 to 3.1.5, which involves upgrading Hibernate 5 to 6.2. This has totally broken my schema-based multitenancy setup. I am using Postgres 12 along with Spring Data JPA, with various entity classes and JpaRepository interfaces. I test with Testcontainers.

My schema-based multitenancy setup uses implementations of `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` and `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`, which are `@Component` Beans. After the upgrade, I am only able to get tests involving a repository and Testcontainers to pass if I do not register the connection provider with Hibernate properties (when running in isolation); however, that makes it impossible for the project to build (with Maven).

In Spring Boot 2.7, I had to make both my multitenancy components implement `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` and register themselves with Hibernate properties through `AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_ ...`
(and I'm aware that the `MULTI_TENANT` type property itself was removed in Hibernate 6). This was the only way I was able to get the app to recognise the components for multitenancy. In Spring Boot 3.1.5 with Hibernate 6.2, the `TenantIdentifierResolver` registers itself fine - it's only the connection provider that causes tests to fail. But if I don't register it, my app can't build at all, and I have no multitenancy setup.

The error when I register the connection provider:

```
    org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:466)
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:601)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
 at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
 at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
 at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
 at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy228.save(Unknown Source)
 at org.fake.pckge.name.TestContainerTests.saveEntityToRepository(TestContainerTests.java:36)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
 at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:78)
 at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:282)
 at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:232)
 at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:164)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:420)
 ... 85 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
```

I have tried registering the connection provider in other ways, such as in a `HibernateConfig` Bean, or in `MultiTenancyJpaConfiguration` as in the suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77434924/cannotcreatetransactionexception-in-multi-tenant-spring-boot-app-after-upgrading/77727498), as well as in application properties. Wherever I register it, I have the same issue. I am wondering if it’s a chicken-and-egg situation, where the instantiation of the Beans is too slow for the connection to be established with the right schema. One other piece of the puzzle is that my `TenantBasedConnectionProvider` relies on a custom `@Configuration` Bean which loads some properties from the application YAML, such as the names of schemata to use. However, like I say, this worked fine in Spring Boot 2.7 and should be possible, given Hibernate properties are also set in the application YAML.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it. It was a red herring. While debugging I had introduced the `@Container` annotation in my `PostgresIntegrationTest` interface that all Testcontainer tests implement. This annotation closes the Testcontainer after the first test runs. You cannot use `@Container` or `@ServiceConnection` - you have to use `@DynamicPropertyRegistry` and call `container.start()` within the method

Another issue was that in `MultiTenantConnectionProvider.getConnection` I had put the connection inside a try block’s parenthesis, which meant the connection would get closed automatically. You have to leave it open and allow Hibernate to manage it